# Target/Looping through elements separately without ID or class in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to target each table element with javascript not being able to modify the html?

The tables are user controlled and lacks both ID and class and all I can do is:

```
var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table');
```

Is there any possibility to modify each table separetly? The same code should apply but I don't want to mix table data between the tables when looping through each table cell etc.

I've done my best to try to explain what I'm trying to achieve, but enlighten me if I need to elaborate. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Fyi, I'm not able to use jQuery in this project.

Comment: That will give you an array of tables, loop over the tables like: for table in tables and then for each table call  table.getElementsByTagName("td") to pick out the TDs or whatever you need on a per table basis.  Or call table.childNodes, which will likely be the TRs and then operate as needed

Comment: getElementsByTagName returns the collection of all tables. If you loop through that collection, you can call an external function with the table as parameter and keep all variables local in that function if you're afraid that data gets mixed up.

Comment: @xkickflip I think that would work too, but I can't seem to do "table.getElementsByTagName("td"). Perhaps because you can't get elements by tag name from something you've already targeted with the same method? I'm not sure.

Comment: @xkickflip Oh, nevermind. It works. I just forgot to add the [index] after the table when looping through the tables. I would accept it if you post as answer. Thanks.

Comment: sure writing it up for you now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the docs on [element.getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Felement.getElementsByTagName), which as Me.Name stated returns an HTMLCollection. So it's all the tables and you can loop over them to operate on them individually.

Also it can be called from any element and will start its search from that node. So calling it on document first to find all the tables in the page and then when called on each table it will only return matching child nodes of that table element.

Use it like this:

```
// Get all the tables in the page
var tables = document.getElementsByTagName('table');

// Iterate the tables and operate on the internals of each separately
for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {

    // calling this on the table will limit the search to children of this table
    var tds = tables[i].getElementsByTagName('td');

    for (var j = 0; j < tds.length; j++) {
        console.log("TD contains: " + tds[j].innerHTML);
    }

}
```

I also made a [fiddle for good measure](https://jsfiddle.net/xkickflip/m13g3592/)